# Searching a value in multiple columns within group and subset if true

Tags: r, row, subset

I aim to subset groups within groups, where `cond==1` and other conditions `==3` three times. So, first, I look at `group` within `id`. Next, I look at `cond1==1` only. If `cond1==1`, I count how many conditions take value `3`. If I see three conditions take value `3` then I take that entire `group` but within `id`.

Here is `df`:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(rep(450, 4),rep(500, 4)),
                group = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2,2)),
                cond1 = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1),
                cond2 = c(1,3,3,1,3,2,3,1),
                cond3 = c(3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                cond4 = c(3,2,2,3,3,1,2,3),
                cond5 = c(3,2,3,3,3,1,2,3))
```

Here is how `df` looks like:

```
   id group cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 cond5
1 450     1     1     1     3     3     3
2 450     1     2     3     3     2     2
3 450     2     1     3     1     2     3
4 450     2     2     1     2     3     3
5 500     1     1     3     3     3     3
6 500     1     2     2     1     1     1
7 500     2     2     3     2     2     2
8 500     2     1     1     3     3     3
```

For instance, from that data frame, group 1 for `id==450` is eligible for subsetting, because in the same row, where `cond==1`, other conditions take value 3 at least three times. Also, group 2 for `id==500` also has `cond==1` and at least three values `3` in the row. The order does not matter.

Here how the result should look:

```
   id group cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 cond5
1 450     1     1     1     3     3     3
2 450     1     2     3     3     2     2
7 500     2     2     3     2     2     2
8 500     2     1     1     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(ind = rowSums(select(., cond2:cond5) == 3) == 3) %>% 
  group_by(id, group) %>% 
  filter(if(any(ind & cond1 == 1)) all(ind[cond1==1]) else FALSE)%>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-ind)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#    id group cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 cond5
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   450     1     1     1     3     3     3
#2   450     1     2     3     3     2     2
#3   500     2     2     3     2     2     2
#4   500     2     1     1     3     3     3
```

Comment: I only look at rows, where ```cond1==1```, and I also want the entire group taken with that row.

Comment: @Laura in that case `df %>% 
    filter(rowSums(select(., cond2:cond5) == 3) > 2, cond1 == 1)`

Comment: @Laura the group by part is not clear.  Because if you do group  by 'group', then only one of the rows have 'cond1 = 1

Comment: thnx, but still, the ```group``` is gone then. I need it all to be taken. Like in the example, you can see, every ```id``` has full ```group```.

Comment: @Laura The issue is that `df %>% group_by(group) %>%  filter(rowSums(select(., cond2:cond5) %>% filter(cond1 ==1) == 3) > 2 )` there would be 6 rows

Comment: @Laura you can check after creating a column.  `df %>% mutate(ind = rowSums(select(., cond2:cond5)  == 3) > 2) %>% group_by(id, group)` how do you want to filter the 'ind'

Comment: I changed the initial df so that it corresponds with the desired result.

Comment: @Laura do you need `df %>% mutate(ind = rowSums(select(., cond2:cond5) == 3) > 2) %>% group_by(id, group) %>% filter(cond1 == 1 & ind)`

Comment: it's still not exactly like in the question. I changed the initial data so that it would be clearer. sorry about that. `cond1` should have a pair too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213884/discussion-between-laura-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
r <- do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
        split(df, df[c("id", "group")]),
        function(v) subset(v, rowSums(v[-c(1:3)] == 3) >= 3)
    )
)
dfout <- `row.names<-`(r[order(r$id,r$group),],NULL)
```

such that

```
> df
   id group cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 cond5
1 450     1     1     1     3     3     3
2 450     1     2     3     3     2     2
3 450     2     1     3     1     2     3
4 450     2     2     1     2     3     3
5 500     1     1     3     3     3     3
6 500     1     2     2     1     1     1
7 500     2     2     3     2     2     2
8 500     2     1     1     3     3     3
```

---

If you want to keep the row number from the original data frame, you can try

```
r <- Reduce(
    rbind,
    lapply(
        split(df, df[c("id", "group")]),
        function(v) subset(v, rowSums(v[-c(1:3)] == 3) >= 3)
    )
)
dfout <- r[order(as.integer(rownames(r))), ]
```

which gives

```
> dfout
   id group cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4 cond5
1 450     1     1     1     3     3     3
3 450     2     1     3     3     2     3
5 500     1     1     3     3     3     3
8 500     2     1     1     3     3     3
```

Comment: thank you. but here as well. the group is gone. I need it all to be taken. May I kindly ask you to get the result look exactly like in the question?

Comment: ```cond1``` should have a pair while now it has only value 1. the other rows should be also there. Also, only rows with three values should be taken.

Comment: @Laura I don't understand why row 2 and row 7 are selected...they obviously don't have at least three columns from `cond2` to `cond5` that are equal to 3

Comment: right. but they are from the same ```group``` where ```cond1``` has three values. that's why I decided to post the question. it's tricky to keep the other unmatched rows.

Comment: yes. it's right at the end of the post. Also, I edited the text: I need three values, not at least three. Sorry.